# DJango contains does not work on JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have created model like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()
```

and data filed has this structure:

```
Customer.objects.create(name='David', data={
    'key1': 'text1',
    'key2': 'text2',
    },
})
```

The problem is when I want to query by contains it doesn't return any result.

```
Customer.objects.filter(data__key1__contains='t')
```

Generated sql query result does not serve correct sql for 'json like' structure.

Comment: afaik this is not possible; you can try to write your own lookup filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
Customer.objects.filter(data__key1__icontains='t')
```

Comment: I am wondering about the reason why icontains worked but contains didn't?

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains

```
Customer.objects.filter(data__contains={'key1': 'text1'})
```

> The returned objects are those where the given dict of key-value pairs are all contained in the field.

Comment: oh, allright. I missunderstand this [part of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#containment-and-key-operations). It's write :
JSONField shares lookups relating to containment and keys with HStoreField.

Answer (score 3):

JSONField in Django is saved with json.dumps()

You can try:

```
import json
search = json.dumps({'key1': 'text1'})[1:-1] # removed { and }
Customer.objects.filter(data__contains=search)
```

If this code fail, you can try the next:

```
search = '"key1":"text1"'
Customer.objects.filter(data__contains=search)
```